# Can not access the images from the webapp folder in Grails 3

Tags: grails

I'm using grails 3.2.7 application and I can't access the images in the webapp folder

I tried to set some images in the auth.gsp (spring-security-core) But it is not getting displayed.

> Here is the code

```
<img height="100" width="252"style="background-color: #556a7f"
                                            src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'Standout-Logo-2.png')}"
                                            class="img-responsive" alt="Utility Application" />
```

Can someone help?

> Here is the folder structure

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should be storing your images under `grails-app/assets/images` folder which is standard for Grails 3.x

Comment: Thanks and one more thing, as you said i placed the image folder under grails-app/assests and i need to fetch an image from jquery-ui-images folder which is a sub folder of  image folder so how can i do that ? can i do like <asset:image:jquery-ui-images src="sample.png" class="blue"/>

Comment: <asset:image src="subfolder/image.png"/>